# SQL How to retrieve first row when value changed?

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with ID's, dates, and a flag.  I'd like to retrieve the first record within a certain year where the flag has explicitly changed from 0 to 1.

```
ID    DATE        FLAG
1    2019-01-31     0
1    2019-02-28     1
1    2019-03-31     1

2    2019-01-31     1
2    2019-02-28     1
2    2019-03-31     1
2    2019-04-30     0
2    2019-05-31     1

3    2019-01-31     0
3    2019-02-28     1
3    2019-03-31     0
3    2019-04-30     1
```

So my expected result would be for **1** it would be 2019-01-31, **2** would be excluded, and **3** would be 2019-02-28.

So far I have this query which works for the most part, but when I'm doing QA, it seems the query is not excluding those who start at 1, switch to 0, then back to 1.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.ID,
    Date, 
    Flag
 FROM table t
WHERE Flag = '1' 
  AND t.Date > (SELECT MAX(t2.Date) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND t2.Flag = '0' AND t2.Date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31') 
AND t.Date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date);
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

EDIT: I've added [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a892c/3/0)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @JosephYi but there's no _change_ for 2019-05-31, it only has value of `1`

Comment: @JosephYi Yes, the query is returning 2019-05-31, If i remove any of those explicit filters nothing gets returned.

Comment: @JoYi don't want to include 2 though, I only wanted to look for those who were 0 before and 1 after, and excluding those who were 1 before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the first `1` - for series that start with `0` only.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
select id, min_date
from (
    select 
        id,
        flag,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by date) rn,
        min(case when flag = 1 then date end) over(partition by id) min_date
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1 and flag = 0
```

The subquery ranks records having the same `id` by `date` and computes the date of the first `1` flag in the group; thie outer query filters on the first record per group, ensures that it has a `0` flag, and displays the computed date.

Comment: Thanks, this got me the result I needed!!

Answer (score 4):

Use `lag()` to get the previous flag and then aggregate:

```
select id, min(date)
from (select *,
             lag(flag) over (partition by id, year(date) order by date) as prev_flag
      from temp
     ) t
where flag = 1 and prev_flag = 0
group by id, year(date);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a892c/54)

This returns the results for each year.  You can, of course, filter by the year in the subquery if you like.

Comment: where did `user_id` come from? :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck . . . Seemed like a better name than `id`.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff this would work as well, but I was looking to exclude those who flags started off as 1, I should of clarified that a bit better.